# How to get my weight in linear layout to properly align the buttons?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I am trying to configure my button layouts and cannot get the structure to properly form. When I run the code on the VM it makes the ImageButton advertisement take up ove fifty percent of the screen despite the weight being only 10%. Each image button references an image stored in drawable-ldpi, and each are roughly 1 KB in size and the activity code is basic with no additions, this is purely graphic interface at the moment through the main xml.

INTENDED LAYOUT:

```
 _______________________
|        logo          |
|______________________|
|       search         |
|______________________|
|                      |
|     featured         |
|                      |
|______________________|
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|    |     |     |     |
|____|_____|_____|_____|
|     advertisement    |
|______________________|
```

ANDROID MAIN.XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mytastelogo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:src="@drawable/mytastelogo_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/featuredpanel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mycollection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/mycollection_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myrecommendations"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/myrecommendations_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/topitems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/topitems_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/randomitem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/randomitem_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="end" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/advertisement"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it man :-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mytastelogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/featuredpanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mycollection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myrecommendations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/topitems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/randomitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/advertisement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `layout_height` to `0dp` when your orientation is `vertical`. When it is `horizontal`, set your `layout_width` to `0dp`.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: That made the button disappear completely and left the other buttons stuck at the top still.

Comment: When your LinearLayout orientation is horizontal, your `layout_width` should be 0dp, when it is vertical, your `layout_height` should be 0dp.

Comment: Yeah that's originally how I had my code in a previous question and the answer to fixing that was to change 0dp to match_parent. Now when I switch back I'm back on the problem of the buttons not appearing at all.

Answer (score -1):

All the items with weights that will determine their height should have android:layout_height set to 0dp.

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Similarly for items that width is to be determined by weight, you have to set

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: This caused the set of buttons in the layout to just completely dissapear.

Comment: It you want the height to be decided by weight, you make height equal to 0dp and assign weight. If you want to assign widths by weights, you do it for width property, but keep the height as a normal value.